# Visualizing the minimization of $\|Ax-b\|_2^2$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, visualization, quadratic-programming

Consider the least-squares problem

$$\text{minimize} \quad \|Ax-b\|_2^2$$

where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $b$ is an $m$-vector.

How does it looks like geometrically? Could someone draw a picture so I could visualize it?

Comment: I'll let you draw your own picture, although you can find plenty on the web (and even in my YouTube multivariable math lecture—linked in my profile—on least squares). You are trying to find the point $Ax$, thus in the column space (or image) of $A$, closest to $b$. So you seek the orthogonal projection $p$ of $b$ into the column space. If $A$ has rank $n$, the unique $\bar x$ with $A\bar x = p$ will be the minimizer and your least squares solution.

Comment: @TedShifrin I can't find the video, what's the exactly title?

Comment: Look at lectures 53 and 54 of MATH 3500. :)

Comment: Think of a *convex* bowl. If the height of the minimum (or minima) is zero, then $A x = b$ has at least one solution. If the height of the minimum (or minima) is strictly positive, then $A x = b$ is infeasible.

Comment: @TedShifrin can we make requests for lectures you put on youtube?

Comment: @WillJagy, haha! I don't know how sarcastic you're being. But I'm in CA and a retired bum, now. I had students to teach and to do the videos. I do wish I'd done some diff geo and diff top videos, but it was too late .... Now I just have a document cam, and lecturing to myself isn't the same. :(

Comment: @TedShifrin I was trying to be humorous, and I knew you were retired and most likely not teaching on any schedule.